# Autofac resolves Func even if not registered

Tags: c#, autofac

I've set up an autofac container that should contain some `Func<IReadonlyCollection<T>>`. To my surprise, `Resolve` doesn't throw an exception when the `Func` is not registered. Even better, it seems there is somehow a Func created that returns an empty collection.

What I did:

```
var container = IoCBuilder.Container;
var fooProvider = container.Resolve<Func<IReadOnlyCollection<Foo>>>(); // Doesn't throw if Func is actually not registered

var foos = fooProvider(); // Gives an empty collection
```

In the container, several other stuff is registered, but definitely not one single `Func<T>`. (I actually recognized this behavior because I forgot to register the required `Func<T>` and wondered how there could be an empty collection).

Does someone know why this is / how to get an exception when the Func is not registered?

Comment: That is by design https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html

Comment: Also https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#supported-relationship-types

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi for the quick reply. Is there a good way to manage Func<T> by autofac? The goal was to not introduce interfaces containing only one method.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Do you want to disable all default registration provided by autofac ?